# Import an updating appending CSV to MS SQL Server without data loss

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, bulkinsert

I am new to SQL; I am looking for a simple way (without existing tools)

I have CSV file that keeps getting appended and saved.  I am saving it into dropbox which I have on my windows server.  I want to import it into a SQL table every 10 minutes.  A new row gets appended to the CSV as quick as every 30 seconds.

There is a break at the end of the day so I could set the CSV file to delete each night.

I would like a way to ensure that I do not import duplicates and that I do not miss out on any data.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Create an SSIS package to execute every 30 seconds, which pulls data and dump into a staging table in sql server. Create an after insert trigger on that staging table which does an `UPSERT` to the actual target table from staging table. happy days

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments.  Why would you execute every 30seconds rather than 10 minutes?  also would you have SSIS delete the data or just let the native app delete at end of day to ensure no loss of information?

Comment: Sorry I have just read the question again, I thought your file is over written every 30 seconds. Yes you should execute the package every 10 minutes it makes more sense.